# Error while appending to columns (to ndarray)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have ndarray of shape:

```
(20640, 7)
```

I'm trying to add new columns:

```
np.append(x, [m[:,0], m[:,1]], axis = 1)
```

where:

```
m[:,0].shape = m[:,1].shape = (20640,)
```

And I'm getting error:

```
ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 0, the array at index 0 has size 20640 and the array at index 1 has size 2
```

simple example to get this error:
import numpy as np

```
x = np.ones((20640, 7))
m = np.ones((20640, 2))
np.append(x, [m[:,0], m[:,1]], axis = 1)
```

How can I add those 2 columns ?

Comment: can you provide a minimal example? (and the expected output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to concatenate `x` and `m[:,0]`/`m[:,1]` as columns, use `np.c_`:

```
np.c_[x, m[:,0], m[:,1]]
```

Example:

```
x = np.zeros((20640, 7))
m = np.ones((20640, 2))
np.c_[x, m[:,0], m[:,1]]
```

output:

```
array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 1., 1.],
       ...,
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 1., 1.]])
```